# How to identify a single div element among set of elements in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a react app with a list of Div elements to create some Cards. Each card has 'read more' button to expand and collapse a paragraph and I toggle it for each mouse click. **My problem is, for each click, it expand paragraphs in all cards instead only paragraph in the card I clicked. So I can't identify the clicked (this) card**.

Component:

```
class BidCard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            readMoreOpen: false,
        }
    }

    readMore() {
        this.setState({ readMoreOpen: !this.state.readMoreOpen })
    }

    render() {

        const { articles } = this.props;

        return (
            articles.map(article => {
                return (
                    <div className="projectCardRoot" key={article.id}>
                        <div className="projectCardMainLogin">
                            <div className="projectCardMiddle">
                                <p className={this.state.readMoreOpen ? 'openFullParagraph' : 'closeFullParagraph'} id="projectCardDesc">{article.description}</p>
                                <div className="cardReadMore desktopDiv" onClick={this.readMore.bind(this)}>Read more</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            })
        )
    }
}

export default BidCard;
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: How many cards can be expanded together?

Comment: Maybe use another component that is just 1 card. So you have this component `BidCards` and inside the  `articles.map(article => { return (  <div className="projectCardRoot" key={article.id}> <BidCard props here /></div>)})` And pass the readMoreOpen method as a prop. And do not use same id for each card. You can make a `const` component for 1 card. Not a class component.

Comment: @RohanAgarwal only one card

Comment: Then, instead of keeping the logic for closing/opening the cards inside the BidCard component, keep it outside on a parent component, and control it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save id of the expanded card to the state and the check it when rendering items:

```
class BidCard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      readMoreOpen: [],  // Use array here
    }
  }

  // Add card id to the expanded array if not already there, otherwise remove it
  readMore = (id) => {
    this.setState(state => {
      if (state.readMoreOpen.includes(id)) {
        return {readMoreOpen: state.readMoreOpen.filter(readId => readId !== id)}
      }
     return {readMoreOpen: [...state.readMoreOpen, id]}
    })
  }

  render() {

    const { articles } = this.props;

    return (
      articles.map(article => {
        return (
          <div className="projectCardRoot" key={article.id}>
            <div className="projectCardMainLogin">
              <div className="projectCardMiddle">
                {/*Check if the item is in expanded items array */}
                <p className={this.state.readMoreOpen.includes(article.id) ? 'openFullParagraph' : 'closeFullParagraph'} id="projectCardDesc">{article.description}</p>
                <div className="cardReadMore desktopDiv" onClick={() => this.readMore(article.id)}>Read more</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        )
      })
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: simple map should be enough in here `this.props.articles.map(article => article.id === id ? true : false)` - includes + filter + spread operator seems to be too many array operations :)

Comment: Hmm, interesting approach, however now you're setting the state (I'm using state, not props) to array of booleans, so next time you can't compare that to an `id`.

Comment: in this case I would keep only string of expanded article id in the state, there is no need to keep whole array :D.
btw, it's safer to use array from props - more bullet proof

Comment: Yeah, my solution is more for the case when you want to have multiple items expanded.

Comment: for multiple items expanded I would move the expand method to child component :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to keep expanded state per every card.
I would recommend to create component for card

```
            articles.map(article => {
                return (
                    <Article key={article.id} {...article} />
                )
            })
        )
```

```
 class Article extends Component {

 state = {
   readMoreOpen: false 
 }

 readMore() {
        this.setState(state => ({ readMoreOpen: !state.readMoreOpen }))
    }

 render () {
  const {description} = this.props;
  return (<div className="projectCardRoot" >
                        <div className="projectCardMainLogin">
                            <div className="projectCardMiddle">
                                <p className={this.state.readMoreOpen ? 'openFullParagraph' : 'closeFullParagraph'} id="projectCardDesc">{description}</p>
                                <div className="cardReadMore desktopDiv" onClick={this.readMore.bind(this)}>Read more</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>)
}

}
```

Other approach is to keep array of booleans with information of which article div should be currently expanded in this method you will need to update state with id of expanded article

```
readMore(id) {
  this.setState({ articles: this.props.articles.map(article => article.id === id ? true : false) } )
}
```

and in render use boolean from state as information if it should be expanded

Answer (score 1):

That's because all your cards currently share the same source of truth. You used a ternary operator to determine what class a Card would have depending on the state-value. Well, all Cards are using the same state-value to compare, so understandably, if one is affected, then all would be too.

There's more than one way to resolve this, but the most appropriate would probably be to create a separate Card Component. This makes it so each Card component has their own state to keep track of.

See working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-mahavira-wz8iu

**Parent.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Card from "./Card";

import "./styles.css";

class BidCard extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { articles } = this.props;

    return articles.map(article => {
      return <Card article={article} />;
    });
  }
}

BidCard.defaultProps = {
  articles: [{ description: "woof" }, { description: "meow" }]
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<BidCard />, rootElement);
```

**Card.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Card = ({ article }) => {
  const [readOpen, setReadOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="projectCardRoot" key={article.id}>
      <div className="projectCardMainLogin">
        <div className="projectCardMiddle">
          <p
            className={readOpen ? "openFullParagraph" : "closeFullParagraph"}
            id="projectCardDesc"
          >
            {article.description}
          </p>
          <div
            className="cardReadMore desktopDiv"
            onClick={() => setReadOpen(!readOpen)}
          >
            Read more
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

Answer (score 1):

I did a few modifications to your code. This way it should work.

I added comments that explain the the changes. The main idea is that you should not simply store the boolean `readMoreOpen` status (which in your code is treated as a kind of shared between all the cards) but specific card identity.

My changes works if there could be only one "expanded" card at any moment. If your design supposes that there could be a few "expanded" cards at the same time the solution would be more complex though not much.

```
class BidCard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        //  the way you've tried to keep status (open/closed) it wasn't tied to any speciifc card
        //  you should store this specific card instead
        this.state = {
            //readMoreOpen: false,
            expandedCard: null,
        }
        this.readMore = this.readMore.bind(this);
    }

    readMore(article) {
        //this.setState({ readMoreOpen: !this.state.readMoreOpen })
        this.setState({expandedCard: article})
    }

    render() {

        const { articles } = this.props;
        const { expandedCard } = this.state;

        return (
            articles.map(article => {
            //  the look of each card depends on state.expandedCard only if article == expandedCard it's shown with 'openFullParagraph' class
            return (
                    <div className="projectCardRoot" key={article.id}>
                        <div className="projectCardMainLogin">
                            <div className="projectCardMiddle">
                                <p className={article == expandedCard ? 'openFullParagraph' : 'closeFullParagraph'} id="projectCardDesc">{article.description}</p>
                                <div className="cardReadMore desktopDiv" onClick={() => this.readMore(article)}>Read more</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            })
        )
    }
}

export default BidCard;
```